# Image/Drawing pixel comparison tool

Tags: testing, automated-tests, pixel, autocad, cad

I'm currently doing software testing of a CAD software and there are many scenerio where i need to compare the drawings.

Like for example there is a tool "X", If i use that tool it will create a circle based on the parameters,What i want to test is if we gave the same parameters again and use that tool whether i'm getting the same circle as before or Is there any changes ?

So i would like to ask the stack-overflow community for suggestions regarding the software tools which is apt for testing these kind of test cases and the methodology of testing.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically or manually?

Comment: Is it possible you are looking for UI Automation testing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools

Comment: @abenci Thanks a  lot for the reply, But this is a GUI automation tool and that's not what i'm looking for, what i'm looking is to perform a image comparison tool/process which will help me o compare each PIXELS and compare the original image with the expected image.Any tools you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

AutoCAD has had a DWG Compare utility since the 2019 version.

[https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-628460AC-6F4C-4ABF-B2D3-85D9D813891A-htm.html#:~:text=Use%20the%20DWG%20Compare%20feature,used%20to%20show%20the%20differences.&text=Click%20Application%20menu%20%3E%20Drawing%20Utilities,not%20have%20any%20open%20drawings](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-628460AC-6F4C-4ABF-B2D3-85D9D813891A-htm.html#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20DWG%20Compare%20feature,used%20to%20show%20the%20differences.&text=Click%20Application%20menu%20%3E%20Drawing%20Utilities,not%20have%20any%20open%20drawings).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, But we have our own custom Software and the functionality in the AUtoCAD is not in our tool.So we have to use some other third party tools to achieve it.I would like to know how best we can simulate this and which all tools is useful for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Resemble opensource project: https://rsmbl.github.io/Resemble.js/. It can be easily adapted to any programming language.